# How to embed an image to use with wx.iconfrombitmap(wx.bitmap(path)) python

Tags: python, wxpython, embed

I have a python app, that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542551/how-to-create-a-taskbaricon-only-application-in-wxpython) and modified to my needs, but I would like to put the images I use for icons within the script, I am aware there might be performance issues but it's not a problem at the moment, all I need is leave all the files in one, so I can change with my friends and across my computers easily.
So my question is, how can I use an embedded icon image (png files, can be any type) with this line of code that it gets a path to a file, in place of the file itself?

```
   def set_icon(self, path):
    icon = wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(path))
    self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)
```

I tried with img2py, base64, nothing worked, so I thought it might be the path needed not the file.
How could I change/modify the script (or the wx lib) to make it work with embedded files instead of their paths?

Answer (score 4):

The way I usually accomplish this is to combine base64 and zlib

Generate the embedded image data by

```
    from zlib import compress
    from base64 import b64encode
    with open("image.png", "rb") as fileobj:
        data = b64encode(compress(fileobj.read()))
```

copy 'data' to your script using triple quotes and inserting line breaks as needed.

`data = """Tm90IGFjdHVhbCBwaWN0dXJlIGRhdGE="""`

When you need to re-create the image data, just reverse the encoding and compression

```
from base64 import b64decode
from zlib import decompress
image_data = decompress(b64decode(data))
```

How you re-create your bitmap object depends on your version of wxpython. Using the phoenix build you can call create a wx.Image from a stream and then a wx.Bitmap from an image

```
from io import BytesIO
stream = BytesIO(bytearray(image_data)) # just bytes() for py3
image = wx.Image(stream, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY) # wx.ImageFromStream for legacy wx
bitmap = wx.Bitmap(image) # wx.BitmapFromImage for legacy wx
```

In my uses I haven't noticed a performance impact, even when using several embedded files

Comment: There are some tools included with wxPython that help encode an image file into a python module as a `PyEmbeddedImage` object, which has methods for turning it into a `wx.Image`, `wx.Bitmap` or etc. See `python -m wx.tools.img2py --help`