# Is it possible to convert VTK into OSX framework bundle?

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, objective-c++, vtk

I want to pack the VTK framework inside my App like a .framework bundle in OSX.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, please help me to do it.

I have downloaded the source of latest release 5.10.1

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Bundle is just a directory with some defined structure. See [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1) for the details.

Comment: This document shows how to do it with Xcode. As VTK is a cmake project and its platform independent, I was wondering whether it is possible to make a framework out of the binary I have. I have to source code and its too large to add to an Xcode project. Besides the code is in C++ rather than Objective-C.

Comment: That document shows what is framework in general. As I said before it is just a directory where you place you headers, binaries and other resources if any. See "Anatomy of Framework Bundles". And doesn't matter what language C++ or Objective-C (you can even mix them) - your framework will have only headers and your binary. By the way - you can create Xcode project using cmake but that is not required.

Comment: I'm to sure about the binary myFramework mentioned in the documentation. That is a compiled binary. Can I make a working framework without that binary. The reason for my concern is There is no such binary available in VTK. All the components are dyld files. That is dynamic binary. Please help me further to make it.

Comment: And why do you need a framework then? Why not just use those dylibs. Just copy them to your application's bundle. Or may be I just misunderstood your question?

Comment: I think that is something I could do. But I was wondering how do I tell the linker to find the libraries in the lib folder inside my application bundle.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596945/building-osx-app-bundle there is nice and full answer for your question.