# Disable Terminal for Command Line Tool

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, command-line, terminal

I programm an artificial life simulation on my mac with Xcode in C++/OpenGL.
Due to the fact that my programm has a visual output in a seperated window,
I do not need the terminal, while running the concrete programm.

Nevertheless the terminal opens when I run my application throwing '/path/programm ; exit;' at its user. I guess that is for debuging? Or maybe standard because it is a command line tool?

So if I want to make a proper looking application out of it, which does not bother its users with command line outputs, what do I have to do?

If it is inherent of the command line tool to open the terminal do I have to migrate the source code to a cocoa app or Qt even though I yet do not need these build interfaces?

Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you don't want the terminal to be shown when the user double-click your app ?

In this case you should [create a `.app` bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596945/building-osx-app-bundle) and embed your binary into it.

I just tested with the basic "Hello world" Xcode command line template, it works fine.

Comment: Very well! Fyi, just make a new folder (with the name of your exec data) and a subfolder (named 'Contents') and within Contents again two subfolder (named 'MacOS' and 'Resources'). Throw your exec data into the MacOS folder and add '.app' to the main folder. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@echo off
```

In the part off your code that requires the terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not do it. First under Unix it would be system("echo off"); and secondly it just adds off to the comand line output.