# Running OSX Bundle via Open

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, bundle, cpack

I'm trying to make an OSX bundle using CMake/CPack on OSX that involves OpenCV and Qt (although I don't think those dependencies matter at this point). Everything compiles and the bundle is created fine, and I have a script that modifies the necessary library paths such the executable I'm making works if I run it from the Terminal within the bundle. The problem I'm having is if I try to run the MyApp.app file via the open command or by simply double clicking the app it gives me the error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/
```

I've seen other solutions to other LSOpenURLsWithRole() errors involving modifying permissions, but that hasn't helped me.  Also, this error code is an "unknown error" so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I found this mention of the error number, but I don't think Java is the culprit here... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136975/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this ended up being that the libcocoa.dylib library was not finding the requisite libraries. See [Building OSX App Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596945/building-osx-app-bundle) for a thorough answer on the subject. otool -L is your best friend.